# Wicket : render/refresh RepeatingView without having html tag

Tags: java, wicket

So i have FormControl inside Repeating View and i set html for Repeating view as Wicket:container

I am trying to refresh formControl but because i am stripping wicket tags in output
it gives JS error.

i know wicket:container can not be refreshed. but i am not able to refresh control inside it. I tried setting

```
control.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
control.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

And Html is Something like this

```
<form wicket:id="form">
        <wicket:container wicket:id="repeatingContainer">
        </wicket:container>
</form>
```

here is error i am getting

```
Cannot bind a listener for event "change" on element "id1a3" because the element is not in the DOM
```

i want to remove repeatingContainer html tag from output so it follows bootstrap form layout.

Update:
This code is inside the RepeaterView

```
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="componentGroup">
        <wicket:child/>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

This code wicket Child

```
<div wicket:id="labelContainer">
    <label wicket:id="label"></label>
</div>
<div wicket:id="controlContainer" class="control-container">
    <input wicket:id="input"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us some more code. There must be something inside `wicket:id="repeatingContainer"` that produces normal HTML element (like a `<div>`). What is it and does it have Wicket Component ?

Answer (score 0):

ok so i am able to tackle this down.
I updated component Group div to wicket:container and leave the Repeater as div. So now i am able to refresh. and it works alright.

So this is how it will look like

```
<form wicket:id="form">
    <div wicket:id="repeatingContainer">
        <wicket:container wicket:id="componentGroup">
            <div wicket:id="labelContainer">
                <label wicket:id="label"></label>
            </div>
            <div wicket:id="controlContainer" class="control-container">
                <input wicket:id="input"/>
            </div>
        </wicket:container>
    </div>
</form>
```